# RDS Aurora (MySQL) performing EXTREMELY poorly

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I'm migrating our Amazon RDS MsSQL database to RDS Aurora but I am very impressed by Aurora's lack of performance.

```
UPDATE Cars
SET CurrentDriver_id = (
            SELECT Drivers.Id 
            FROM Drivers 
            WHERE Drivers.Car_id = Cars.Id 
            ORDER BY Drivers.Id DESC 
            LIMIT 1)
WHERE Cars.Id BETWEEN 1 AND 500;
```

I had to limit to the first 500 records so I can even see results in Aurora.

Even limiting to 500 rows, Aurora takes incredibly 55s while MsSQL for all 70.000 records took less than 1 second. 
In this scenario, MsSQL performs almost 8.000x faster than Aurora.

The subject of this topic is not the query itself, nor how it could be improved. It is just a simple update running on 70k Cars and 220k Drivers. It should be nothing to a database.

Cars.Id and Drivers.Id are primary keys. No indexes and no foreign keys.

Is this expected?!

Edit: 
1. Both RDSs are db.t2.medium 
2. MsSQL is a production server with hundreds of users while Aurora is only me.

Comment: It is expected, that poorly written queries perform poorly. So the subject should indeed be how to improve the query.

Comment: How did you move the data from MySQL to Aurora? If you did it manually did you ensure the same indexes were created in Aurora? Are MySQL and Aurora running on the same instance types? Did you ensure that any custom MySQL parameters were also applied to Aurora? Did you `optimize` the tables in Aurora after moving the data into Aurora?

Comment: @EugenRieck So, are you telling me that Aurora performs fine only on smart queries? If so, MsSQL is much better, since it works very well even with poorly written ones.

Comment: @MarkB I used Amazon Migration Services. Both RDS use only Primary Keys, without aditional indexes. Both run on db.t2.medium instances. I didn't optimize the tables after moving the data. I will google about it.

Comment: Check the CPU credits on the RDS instance since you are using t2. Make sure you didn't exhaust the CPU credits when you migrated the database over.

Comment: I will take a look at this. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using an approach that don't use subselect

```
  UPDATE Cars
  inner join Drivers on Drivers.Car_id = Cars.Id  and Cars.Id BETWEEN 1 AND 500
    SET Cars.CurrentDriver_id = Drivers.Id
```

Comment: OMG! After that, Aurora is taking only 1.3s for all rows! Thank you for giving a great anwser instead of critizing.

Comment: @HugoRamos    well if the answer  is so good you can also rate as useful